# Can the C++ compiler or preprocessor convert a symbol to uppercase?

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor

I am trying to use [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) methodologies on an arbitrary collection of mixed-case words such that the text **`MixedCase`** could produce both:

- The compile-time string **`"MixedCase"`**
- The compile-time variable **`const int MIXEDCASE_ID`**

I am using gcc, and gcc extensions would be acceptable.

Is it possible for C++ to convert test in the code to uppercase?  E.g., such that

CONVERT(abc)

would produce the symbol `ABC`?  **If not, is there a solution beyond typing every sample twice in the code?**

***Edit:***  Consider that there is no restriction on the input format.  `Mixed` or `"Mixed"` or `'M', 'i', 'x', 'e', 'd'` or `0x4d 0x69 0x78 0x65 0x64` (yuck?)...

Comment: templates are solved at compiled time just like the macros, you can use templates to solve this if i have understood your problem correctly.

Comment: @axis you may have.  I'm glad I described the underlying problem.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Do you consider to formulate this as an answer? It would be complete and the question is interesting.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Would you consider deleting the comment, then?  I believe that you left it to be helpful, (thank you), but it's probably discouraging the creative, helpful answers I'm getting.

Comment: Converting `"MixedCase"` to `"MIXEDCASE"` at compile time isn't the problem, but using it as a symbol is.

Comment: A suggestion, if you just want to use the preprocessor, then make everything lowercase.  lowercase is compatible with the existing C types and standard libraries.  Then you get "lowercase" and lowercase_id.  You can use string manipulation to manipulate your strings.  Some people might complain that this breaks some coding convention somewhere (such as constants *must* be all caps).  However, its still valid C and it opens up more options for the preprocessor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you would need to write a build tool that preprocessed (actually prepreprocessed) your source files to make this conversion.  There is no built-in feature in gcc that can do this at compile time.

Comment: +1 for code generation: do it with `sed`, or `awk`, or the scripting language of your choice ... ok, or m4. Just get your build system to invoke it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Well using [chaos pp](https://github.com/rofl0r/chaos-pp) library(which works for C89 and C99 preprocessors) you can do this:

```
CHAOS_PP_CONCAT
(
    (CHAOS_PP_STRING) CHAOS_PP_STRING_TO_UPPER(M i x e d C a s e)
) 
// Expands to MIXEDCASE
```

Valid values for characters are the numerals (0 through 9), the alphabetic characters in the basic source character set (a through z and A through Z), and the underscore (_). Heres an example of using other characters:

```
CHAOS_PP_CONCAT
(
    (CHAOS_PP_STRING) CHAOS_PP_STRING_TO_UPPER(a b C _ 1 0)
)
// Expands to ABC_10
```

It also has macros for stringizing a token as well.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `m4` pre-processor. It can do this and much more.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [the manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/cpp/index.html) yourself. If you can't find anything there that does what you want, you could always create your own preprocessor (which might just amount to a Perl one-liner in your Makefile, for example).